# jQuery draggable appendTo doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, css, draggable

Following Code:

**jQuery**

```
    $('.dragBox').draggable({ 
        axis: 'y',
        appendTo: 'parent',
        containment: [0,0,0,150],
        start: function() {
            $(this).addClass('grabbing');
        },
        stop: function() {
            $(this).removeClass('grabbing');
        }
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="cropBox"><div class="dragBox"></div></div>
</div>
```

But the .dragBox doesn't append to .cropBox.
The y-axis of the inner box doesn't start at 0, it starts at -117. 117 are the pixel distance between .cropBox and the top edge of the window.

**EDIT**

I fixed it

```
startDrag();

$(window).resize(function(){
    startDrag();
});
function startDrag(){
    var xAxis = $('.dragBox').outerWidth() - $('.cropBox img').outerWidth();
    var yAxis = $('.dragBox').outerHeight() - $('.cropBox img').outerHeight();
    var x1 = $('.dragBox').position().left;
    var y1 = $('.dragBox').position().top;
    if( $('.dragBox img').outerWidth() > $('.dragBox img').outerHeight() ) {
        var axis = 'x';
        var containment = [xAxis+x1,0,x1,0];
    } else {
        var axis = 'y';
        var containment = [0,yAxis+y1,0,y1];
    }

    $('.dragBox img').draggable({ 
        axis: axis,
        appendTo: 'parent',
        containment: containment,
        start: function() {
            $(this).addClass('grabbing');
        },
        stop: function() {
            $(this).removeClass('grabbing');
        }
    }); 
}
```

thanks for replies!

Comment: have you tried appendTo('.cropBox')

Comment: if I remember right the appenTo option is for the helper only and has nothing to do with the draggable element itself. And yes I guess I had the same problem, that the helper was on a wrong position.

Comment: @blachawk Yes i allready tried this.

Comment: @ggzone hm here is an code example: http://jsfiddle.net/tTJd4/

Comment: i edited your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tTJd4/1/ by changing the containment from 100 to 80 becouse the problem seems to be a negative top value by -20 pixels. was that your problem?

Comment: the top top value of the dragbox should be absolute to the cropbox. so the top value should be between 0 and 100 or with your edit 0 and 80

Answer (score 0):

As far as I unterstood your posting, you are looking for:

```
 $('.dragBox').draggable({ 
    axis: 'y',
    containment: 'parent',
    start: function() {
        $(this).addClass('grabbing');
    },
    stop: function() {
        $(this).removeClass('grabbing');
    }
});
```